# Is it possible to write a comment after a ';' in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, syntax, comments

In this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerName ASC; -- some comment
```

If a comment is not part of the query/code, why can't I write it after the '**;**' char?
(Just tried it in w3schools example DB)

How can I otherwise create comments at the end of the query, if at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex SQL-Script, the comments make it better readable so it make sense. If you need the query only once the comment is useless.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).